# R LaF package: skip first lines reading fixed column width text file

Tags: r

I am using the LaF package in R to read large text files with fixed column widths. While the LaF function for reading comma separate value files does provide a "skip" option, I don't see the same option for fixed column width files.

For now, I have to open each text file in a editor able to read large text files to remove the first 8 lines. It's cumbersome as I have to wait for the files to load, remove the lines, wait to save..

Any idea how can I do that directly with LaF? For now LaF sends an error message as it expects to get numbers and receive the strings of the first lines I want to remove.

Any way to bypass this missing "skip" option?

Here is the code I use to read the text file:

```
results <- laf_open_fwf("D:/Projects/TestProject4/Scenarios/output.txt",
                          column_types = c("string", "integer", "integer", "integer", "integer", "integer", "double", "double", "double"),
                          column_widths = c(5, 5, 9, 4, 3, 5, 13, 12, 12),
                          column_names = c("ID", "RCH", "GIS", "MONTH", "DAY", "YEAR", "AREAkm2", "FLOW_OUTcms"))
```

Answer (score 1):

For those interested, the solution is to use the `readr` package instead of LaF.

```
library(readr)

d <- read_fwf("yourfile.txt", 
              fwf_widths(c(5, 5, 9, ...),
                         c("ID", "COL1", "COL2", ...)),
              skip = 10,
              progress = interactive())
```